# Detect the print event from acrobat reader inside iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe

I use this tag for showing a pdf document preview

```
<iframe id="reportout" height="750px" src="../PdfDoc/prev.pdf" width="100%"></iframe>
```

It show the document inside adobe reader in IE 11

How can i detect the print event triggred from the default print button of the pdf viewer with javascript 
  i've tried the `window.onafterprint` but it's not working

Comment: What library are you using? `window.onafterprint` isn't a standard `window` event, and is not supported in all browsers (only IE and Firefox at the time of writing).

Comment: Yes, it's an app for IE only

Comment: Then can you expand upon _"but it's not working"_? What isn't happening?  What do you expect to happen? Do you have any console errors? etc

Comment: I've add this simple to test if it catch the print event `  window.onafterprint = function () {
        alert('nouchirra');
    }; `  but nothing happen